# XSL Foreach - Getting The Value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, google-search-appliance

Here is a bit of XML that's in each record:

```
<MT N="usage" V="something"/>
<MT N="usage" V="something else"/>
```

I'm trying to display all of these V values for each record with XSLT, but am having issues targeting the correct value.

```
<xsl:for-each select="MT[@N = 'usage']/@V">
    <xsl:value-of select="V"/>
    11
</xsl:for-each>
```

This outputs "1111", but the value of V isn't displayed. How do I target that?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

select="V" probably is not a node.

What about

```
<xsl:for-each select="MT[@N = 'practice']">
<xsl:value-of select="@V"/>
11
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <xsl:for-each select="MT[@N = 'usage']/@V"> 
>     <xsl:value-of select="V"/> 
>     11 
> </xsl:for-each>
> ```

The `<xsl:value-of>` above is trying to display the value of an element `V` that is a child of the current node. However the current node is an attribute, and attributes by definition have no children. This is the problem that you have.

**Solution**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="MT[@N = 'usage']/@V"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
    11 
</xsl:for-each>
```

Now the `<xsl:value-of>` outputs the string value of the current node -- which was probably intended.